# How to cross compile a C++ library from Windows to Linux? (C++17) Using VS 2019

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries, cross-compiling

I have a C++ library and I need to make a `.a`.  I use a `.lib` for the windows build of my project and need a `.a` for the linux build.

VS says it can do this with a CMake project but I haven't been able to create anything from the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-configure?view=msvc-160).

When I create the `.lib` I use cmake to create a Visual Studio solution.  Then I use MSVC 2019 to create the .lib.

EDIT: My current CMakeLists.txt for the windows library.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9)

add_definitions(-DNOT_USING_CMAKE=0)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "..." CACHE PATH "...")

project(...)

include_directories (...)

#create base library
add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC "")

set_target_properties (${PROJECT_NAME}
  PROPERTIES
  CXX_STANDARD 17
  CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
  CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
)

add_subdirectory (...)
...
add_subdirectory (...)

  install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
         RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
         LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
         ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/archive )
```

Comment: This question is asking for recommendations for build systems, which is going to be more or less opinion based, because there are so many options.  I would recommend looking at the CMake documentation for static library building, if you are open to using CMake. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I'm not really asking for recommendations for build systems, I'm just saying I'm open to solutions using different systems.

I am using cmake and msvc to help me build the .lib but I don't know what would be required to make a .a on windows.

Comment: The solution is to select a system and write the build system code required to compile your `.a` file.  This subject is unfortunately far too involved and broad to be addressed in an answer in any reasonable manner.  There are many resources on how to use CMake to compile a static library in the most general terms.  Do you have a specific question regarding this process?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, I don't think creating a library is far too involved to be answered in a single question.  For example, I added the file above which creates a VS solution which I can build that makes a .lib.  It is my understanding you cannot just make a linux static library in windows using cmake because cmake uses its operating system for context.  I know Microsoft advertises that VS can cross compile using cmake.  I am aware of teh documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-configure?view=msvc-160) and have read it.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I changed the question to ask how it can be done using Visual Studio. Maybe an example project someone knows of somewhere might be helpful.